# Will Ubuntu Server 12.04 run on a system with 8 physical CPUs?

Tags: 12.04, server, cpu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many maximum CPUs does Ubuntu support by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158555/how-many-maximum-cpus-does-ubuntu-support-by-default)

Is it possible to run ubuntu server 12.04 on a server with 8 individual physical processors. As my server has 8 individual physical processors and without them all being used, it is not as powerful as it can be. Any ideas?