# How many maximum CPUs does Ubuntu support by default?

Tags: kernel

<sub>I think this is kernel dependent and probably will change over time depending on the kernel a release uses, correct me if wrong</sub>

I'd like to know two things for all the currently supported Ubuntu releases:

How many maximum CPUs can Ubuntu handle (by default) at the same time with a standard desktop kernel? Is that count different from a server kernel and 32bit/64bit systems?

Where can I find that information on my system?

Comment: similar question in [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/172894/how-many-processors-can-gnu-linux-support), the parameter is `NR_CPUS` I think.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Maximum CPUs (i.e. *cores*) supported by default:

> Note: by 32-bit/64-bit we mean the common `i386/x86_x64` architectures; PPC, ARM, etc. are not included.

#### 12.04 LTS (and later):

- Desktop/Server **32-bit**: 8 cores/CPUs
- Desktop/Server **64-bit**: 256 cores/CPUs (but LiveCD supports 64 by default)

#### 11.10 and below, including 10.04 LTS

- Desktop/Server 32-bit: 8 cores/CPUs
- Desktop 64-bit: 64 cores/CPUs
- Server 64-bit: 256 cores/CPUs

#### How to find the maximum supported by your *running* kernel:

As @otus indicated, open a terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T`, and type:

```
grep NR_CPUS /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

---

> The below is a somewhat technical discussion on what *maximum* really means:

#### The "default" maximum is not the maximum!

- You can recompile the desktop or server kernels to support up to 512 CPUs for 64-bit (8 is max for 32-bit).
- **but even those are not absolute maximums!**:

  - The kernel has "experimental" options for going higher than the "default" maximum
  - The limit for 32-bit with `BIGSMP=y` is 512
  - The limit for 64-bit with `MAXSMP=y` is 4096 (or more!)
  - Just because the kernel supports so many cores on the general i386/x86_64 architecture **does not mean** your hardware will!

Comment: I found an Excellent [Link here](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NR_CPUS.html), but i am not sure about which kernel versions started supporting SMP and incrementing the CPU's , i hope you can include and make it a much detailed and better answer through this. Also SMP support started from Ubuntu 10.04 , as [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/ia64/hardware-supported.html)

Comment: @izx I have edited the title to reflect a more Ubuntu information approach. I am really looking for something that wee can redirect questions like "Does Ubuntu support my X processors system" to this one.

Comment: @BrunoPereira, many thanks for clarifying -- I have updated to "top-post" the necessary info, while including the tech stuff at the bottom for those interested; I will continue to refine in the next few hours to be more newbie-friendly :)

Comment: @izx pro! good job again. regards

Comment: in Ubuntu 20.04 it seems you can use ```dmesg | grep NR_CPU``` which gives me ```[    0.677263] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:8192 nr_cpumask_bits:128 nr_cpu_ids:128 nr_node_ids:1
[    0.916164] rcu:  RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8192 to nr_cpu_ids=128.```

Answer (score 4):

All I know for sure is that precise (12.04) desktop 64-bit `-generic` kernel supports maximum 256 cpus (by default).

You can find the number of CPUs your kernel config supports by doing:

```
grep CONFIG_NR_CPUS /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

Comment: Since in 12.04 there is no longer a separate `-server` kernel, this applies to 64-bit Server systems as well.

Answer (score 2):

It all comes down to how one would define physical CPUs.  Are they equivalent to sockets, so a multicore and/or hyperthreading CPU is counted as a single socket?

> The Ubuntu kernel is configured to support 8 processors / cores in
>   32-bit and 64 processors / cores in 64-bit.<sup>1</sup>

As far as finding that information, I have used Sysinfo and I'm very happy with it.  If you don't have it installed, you can do so by just pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install sysinfo
```

Also to find the Number of processors in a system using terminal, just type:

```
dmesg |grep processor
```

I will keep researching this until I find the perfect answer.

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Wiki Answers](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_many_processors_does_Kubuntu_support#ixzz1zSTEBlKW)</sup>

Comment: This goes to all releases that haven't reached it's EOL?

Comment: This seems like outdated information. Starting with Ubuntu 12.04, the desktop and server kernels are the same. Many server machines have more than 8 processors/cores (and this has been the case for quite some time). It seems implausible that the single kernel, now used in both server and desktop systems, supports only up to 8 logical processors.

Comment: @EliahKagan Is the number the same for 32, and 64 bit?

Comment: @BrunoPereira, Mitch: No. I think it's 8 on 32-bit systems. I have a machine running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit and the [output of `grep CONFIG_NR_CPUS /boot/config-$(uname -r)`](http://askubuntu.com/a/158566/22949) is `CONFIG_NR_CPUS=8`. There aren't too many 32-bit systems that run high-end servers or have more than 8 logical processors these days (though I expect that to change again once low-power systems become more parallel), so this makes sense. If I had info on all the non-EoL releases I'd post an answer, but I don't, at least not currently. Definitely feel free to include this info!

Comment: @BrunoPereira, Eliahkagan, Does this look better, I have deleted the out dated info that you mentioned Eliah.

Comment: @EliahKagan it was a typo. But if it 8 logical, then its 64 cores, right?

Comment: @Mitch The newly updated information (that 32-bit versions can support up to 64 cores) indicates `NR_CPUS` is the number of separate physical processors supported rather than the number of cores. In reflection, that [does seem correct](http://askubuntu.com/a/158566/22949). I do recommend editing to specify the number of separate processors *and* the number of cores in your answer, though.

Comment: @EliahKagan A sigle processor with multiple cores is still treated as logical processors.

Comment: Isn't true that, the Linux kernel can be compiled to support any number of CPUs.